# Why is it bad to use personal pronouns in a CV?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, new-job

I am applying for a new job, and I am rubbish at writing CVs, so I often have a look at the examples and templates on-line, and it says that you should use not use personal pronouns in these examples.
For example

Instead of:

> I Solved an IT issue

You should use:

> Solved an IT issue

Why is it frowned upon or bad to use personal pronouns in a CV/Resume?

EDIT:  Is it acceptable to use I once or twice, or would you advise against it completely?

Comment: This is a very helpful article relating to this question: http://online.wsj.com/news/articles/SB10001424052702304626104579121371885556170

Comment: My top priority is clarity. I have never hesitated to use "I" when the alternative is a convoluted sentence structure and a turgid narrative.

Comment: Just a footnote: In these days of electronic applications, avoiding "I" may simplify extracting quotes from the resume when the applicant is being discussed.

Comment: related: [Should I write my biography in the first or third person?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/15109/168)

Comment: ... On the other hand, in these days if electronic _scoring_ of resumes, the difference may make no difference in the actual process. Things have changed since 2014.

Comment: I have never heard of omitting pronouns, which makes the sentence look incomplete and makes the writer sound less than stellar. Because omitting pronouns sounds like "text speak" people use during SMS conversations.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because it makes the readers go to sleep after the 567th repetition of I. And because it saves space which is helpful when you have 30 years experience and only 2 pages to put it on. And since it is a CV, the reader will assume it was you and no-one else who did the task.

Comment: I Love the answer, it made me smile! +1 to you  :)

Comment: !00%, if used, there will be tons of I`s

Answer (score 17):

You put your name at the top. It is implied that everything on your CV would pertain to you, so there is only a need to include other people (team members) where appropriate.

It gets a little repetitive

- I did this.
- I did that
- I did something else.

This is great if you really want to hammer the point home that "I did ..." but again, it's your CV so it is implied.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think its acceptable to use it once or twice in a CV, just to hammer the point home.

Comment: @georgeh I agree with JeffO's answer overall, but I also think that the occasional "I" is fine - I find stilted and awkward grammar for the sake of avoiding "I" can sometimes be irritating. So yeah, some "I" usage is fine, but that's just my feelings. Others may differ.

Comment: @GeorgeH: Include "I" in narratives only. During portions of the CV where you're bullet-pointing things the repetition is off-putting. But in a narrative, write it as if you were telling someone a story. (+1 to this answer btw)

Comment: repetition is a poor argument against personal pronouns: if you're just writing a list of short sentences that all start with *i did* you've done something wrong. and even impersonal resumes can fall into a repetitious tone.

Answer (score 5):

Because a CV is supposed to be a factual and impersonal description *about* you, not *by* you.  Yes, usually, you do actually write your own CV, but that's not something you're supposed to emphasize.

Basically, write your CV as if you were someone else describing yourself in third person.

Ps. Caveat: Rules are meant to be broken.  Sometimes, writing your CV in an unconventional style might make it stand out and cause a prospective employer to pay more attention to it.  Of course, sometimes it might also just get it sorted into the circular file that much quicker.  It's up to you whether you feel that's a risk worth taking.

Answer (score 1):

While it’s okay to talk directly about yourself in your cover letter, “Me, Myself and I” should be avoided at all costs in your resume. You resume should be concise, neat, and easy for an employer to read. Using pronouns is how we normally structure sentences, but since your resume is a document about your person, using these pronouns is actually redundant.

Answer (score -3):

It is extremely difficult to narrate and not use 'I' once in a while. Not using 'I' at all makes the person sound like a machine. Use 'I' when necessary to sound like a competent writer. If you can't figure that out, take a composition course!
I have 30 years of experience and hate giving out my one-page resume. I'd much rather give out my five-page extended one because it shows *everything* I've accomplished. If an employer doesn't care about that, then maybe I don't care much about that employer either.

Comment: Unfortunately, evidence is that employers don't want to spend more time reading resumes than the have to in order to decide whether to do an interview. Writing an interesting short description, and holding the details for the interview where your ability to explain in depth will serve you better, really is likely to be more effective. This is a CV, not a biography; you want it to have immediate impact and that means keeping it focused on highlights.

Answer (score -3):

Adjusting my position a bit:

This is partly a stylistic question. Avoiding "I" and 'we" and "you" in technical material has been an editorial tic for many decades. Not everyone buys into it.

But there is also a convention of using "telegraphic" style in business reports generally.
(and a result can be considered a report). In this style the pronoun is assumed to be the author of the document unless stated otherwise.

Some people also believe that resumes written in this style might be machine-screened more easily. I thought that myself once; I am less convinced now that natural language parsing is more sophisticated.

As a subscriber to RWRTATP, I am a firm believer in doing whatever makes the document most readable if and when it reaches a human, rather than blindly and absolutely adhering to an arbitrary set of conventions. But this is not a bad one.

Comment: What is RWRTATP? (I have a healthy interest in English oddities) I googled but only this page/answer actually had the acronym. Is it real or sarcastically made up one?

Comment: Real Writers Rewrite To Avoid The Problem. Originated in IBM's internal technical/marketing writer's forum, was propagated to some other communities. Used to dismiss writing "rules" that are not actually good solutions. (Example: rather than avoiding gendered pronouns in examples by saying "the user", one can often rewrite to discuss in terms of named individuals, maintaining an unbiased mix of genders. "Alice" is a lot easier to read, as well as more engaging, even in an example that only involves one person.) Write for clarity, not for conformance; style is a tool, not an absolute.