# Voice perspective to be used when composing a cover letter

Tags: cover-letter

I have a question regarding the appropriate voice perspective to be used when composing a cover letter for job searching in the financial services industry. I vs. you. vs. he / she.

My thinking goes as follows:

First Person I: This demonstrates passion / interest but perhaps would sound too self - centered as its more important to focus on the company and what you can do for it, not the way around.

Second Person You: Speaks directly to the hiring manager but might sound too overbearing / intimidating

Third Person He/She: I don't think this is appropriate at all. Too detached and fails to show interest as well as difficult to establish connection.

**What is most appropriate tone to use balancing interest for the job with out being excessively aggressive / overbearing**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is subjective and about grammar.

Comment: @JimG. I edited the question to improve objectivity. I would feel there would be conventions for this in the industry.

Comment: see also: [Why is it bad to use personal pronouns in a CV?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/22707/why-is-it-bad-to-use-personal-pronouns-in-a-cv)

Answer (score 5):

I don't really understand how you could write a cover letter in anything *except* **first person**?  You are writing it to convince the company to hire you, so you have to talk about yourself:

- I am the person you want for this job. I'm awesome, and your company is awesome, so we should totally get together and make more awesomes.

Second person would be inappropriate unless you're applying to be a hypnotist or Jedi master:

- You are reading a cover letter. You are feeling sleepy.  You will not resist.  This is the droid you are looking for, and you want to hire them.

And third person is for references, not cover letters:

- This cover letter was written by Billy Bob.  He is awesome and you should hire him.